# Oracle enforce SYSDATE to PT

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

EDIT: I do not want to change SYSDATE, now I understand this is not possible unless the Host of the DB changes, I would still like my data to be in Pacific Time so I guess the way to go is using TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIMEZONE

I have a database for which I want to enforce SYSDATE to be Pacific Time. I cannot modify the date of the host for my DB due to business rules and currently SYSDATE is CDT.

I am aware that I can change the timezone for my session, however I cannot control that other users will alter their sessions as well

Is there a way I can enforce users to use PT without modifying the date of the host?

I was thinking maybe a sort of PL/SQL trigger that alters the session every time a new connection to DB is stablished.

Thanks1

Comment: "Pacific Time" and CDT are on United States? Please write time zone offset

Comment: PT = UTC -7
CDT = UTC-5

Comment: Yes, you could write a `after logon` trigger, however the user may change the time zone afterwards at any time. Your approach is wrong, if you need to consider time zones, then use data type `TIMESTAMP WITH (LOCAL) TIME ZONE` and appropriate functions (e.g. `SYSTIMESTAMP` or `LOCALTIMESTAMP`). `DATE` data type is not aware of any time zone information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're asking the right question. You can't do what you're trying to do. `SYSDATE` returns the date and time of the *operating system* the database is running on. It returns a `DATE` value, and `DATEs` are not time zone aware. I guess you could change the time zone of the operating system, but you'd have to talk to your system administrator about that.

You might want to work more with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` which returns a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` value and the display of that can be modified with the session time zone.

I'd say the bigger question is why are you trying to change the time zone for `SYSDATE`?

Comment: Thanks!
Yep, I guess the way to go is to cast the existing date columns to TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIMEZONE.

Answer (score -1):

You can use an "after logon" trigger to set time zone.

Include the following sentence inside trigger:

```
execute immediate 'ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE=''-05:00''';
```

Change "-05:00" with time offset of "Pacific Time"

Comment: `SYSDATE` is returned in the time zone of the database server operating system, thus `ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE ...` has no effect.

Comment: This answer is wrong. TIME_ZONE is for datatype ```TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE```